# s3 sync directory, including the directory itself

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm currently running the aws s3 command:

aws s3 sync 'A' s3://my-bucket

which syncs all contents of the directory A to the bucket, but does not include the directory 'A' itself.

E.g. if 'A' contains 'A-subdir', then the bucket will contain 'A-subdir', not 'A' with 'A-subdir' nested in it.

Is there a way to make s3 sync include the directory 'A' and its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specify the object path you want to have under the bucket - it will default to sync into the "root" of the bucket.

Try instead to specify where you want it to sync:

```
aws s3 sync A s3://my-bucket/A
                            ^^^ the change is here
```